# cut an interval from the dataframe series

Tags: pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime': ['11/12/2019 23:11:11', '11/12/2019 23:22:22', 
                                '11/12/2019 23:33:33',  '11/12/2019 10:10:10',
                                '11/12/2019 23:05:05',  '11/12/2019 23:00:00'], 
                   'value': [1,2,3,4,5,6]}) 
#Please note that the time dtype are all datetime.datetime and not string.
```

Expected
I wish to use pd.cut or anything to cut the 'Datetime' to interval minutes like [0-3 minute], [3-6minute], [6-10 minute] .....  range.

Comment: can you please post the expected dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.cut` accepts datetime to cut

Create bins

`bins = pd.date_range('0:00', '0:09', periods=4)`

then apply it

`pd.cut(df['Datetime'], bins=bins)`

```
1             (2019-12-26, 2019-12-26 00:03:00]
2    (2019-12-26 00:03:00, 2019-12-26 00:06:00]
3    (2019-12-26 00:06:00, 2019-12-26 00:09:00]
```